# Problem in Location Pagination within gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a problem with my pagination in my `GridView`. As you can see, it is positioned on top of registering a new action ("Agregar Acción") and I want it to go to the footer of the GridView.

This is my image and second my aspx code (gridView)

[image]

[image]

In the GridView I only add `AllowPaging` and `PageSize`, & within the `<asp:TemplateField>` I have only text fields and already verified that all labels are closed correctly to prevent it from being from any of these.

How do I position the page selector at the end of the gridview?

Comment: Why your paging has no style? Are you sure that all your tags are correct? BTW, you can change the page selector position using CSS.

Comment: @Maddie do you have a example that you can share me ?